# When sharing my website on social media, a random image gets picked and displayed. Do I have control over which image is shown?

Tags: html

For example when I send the website on facebook, a random image is picked ( which I don't even have on the website anymore ) and displayed along the website title and URL.

I was wondering whether it's possible to pick a specific image that will always be displayed when sending the website to people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the opengraph markup for the page, different sites use different attributes, but here's Facebook's documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup